# How to receive text from the Android soft keyboard without using the key-up event?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-softkeyboard

I'm writing a Android NDK application, (targeted at API 8), which is based on the *hello-gl2* example and so uses a single full-screen OpenGL2.0 view.

I need to bring up the on-screen keyboard and so from the info available on this site i can now bring up the keyboard, send the keyup events to my native application for processing and close the keyboard. All is well until i switch to *Swype* or any other more-advanced-then-stock keyboard input manager and it doesn't work.

After reading the [*KeyEvent* developer doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html%20*KeyEvent*%20developer%20doc) class overview what i'm seeing seems to be the expected behaviour:

> You should never rely on receiving KeyEvents for any key on a soft
>   input method.

So i've been trying to work out a way to capture the output of a IME which i can then pass down to my native application. Unfortunately i'm not getting very far with this at all.

I've got this code in my extended *GLSurfaceView* class:

```
@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs)
{
    outAttrs.actionLabel = "";
    outAttrs.hintText = "";
    outAttrs.initialCapsMode = 0;
    outAttrs.initialSelEnd = outAttrs.initialSelStart = -1;
    outAttrs.label = "";
    outAttrs.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE | EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI;
    outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_NULL;

    return new BaseInputConnection(this, false);
}

@Override
public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor()
{
    return true;
}
```

And i'm calling:

```
public boolean showSoftInput(View view, int flags)
```

passing in the view returned from *getCurrentFocus*, from native code to display the keyboard.

Is it possible to be able to extract the text from the on-screen software keyboard not using the keyup event? Is it possible to update what i've got to be able to do this or should i be looking at a completely different method?

Apologies for the questions, as you can tell, the non-native Java side of Android development is quite new to me.

As a summary my current implementation is based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7425536/1184595%20this%20question) which allows the soft-keyboard text to be captured using key events however i'd like to capture the text not using key events.. (possibly a TextWatcher.. though my View isn't editable?).

Many thanks for any help or advice offered,

Andy

Comment: Just giving this question a bump as i've not been able to resolve this. I've also posted it on the Google Android developer and NDK groups without much luck.

Any help/advice would be much appreciated.
Andy

Comment: I am facing the same issue now, keyboard input works just fine but nothing happens when swype is used. Is there any way to simulate the events?